# Binding a tibble with more than 1 rows and another one with only one row in R

Tags: r, tidyverse

I have two tibbles: the first one with more than one row and second one, with exactly one row.

I want to col bind them, and, for this purpose, I want the second one to have the same number of rows as the first.

I can do this operation with this trick:

```
for (i in colnames(df2)) {
  df1[[i]] <- df2[1,i]
}
```

However, this sounds like a workaround to me. Is there a "tidier" way of doing this (I mean, with tidyverse)?

Comment: just `cbind(df1,df2)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just go for `cbind(df1,df2)`, it will expand the shortest data.frame to match the number of rows of the longest

If you want to use dplyr, you would want a cross join... but dplyr has no cross join yet.

You can create a dummy column on both tables, and `inner_join` on it:

```
df1 %>% 
  mutate(dummy_id=1) %>% 
  inner_join(df2 %>% mutate(dummy_id=1)) %>% 
  mutate(dummy_id=NULL)
```